# Comparison between two algorithms solving fractional knapsack

Tags: dynamic, comparison, knapsack-problem, greedy

I have written the fractional knapsack problem with two algorithms (Greedy and dynamic programming algorithm) and I have to make  a comparison between them ..  I only made a comparison in terms of time and space complexity .. I have no idea about  what additional factors can be used for making comparison between the two algorithms..
I hope that anyone could help me and provides me with any idea .

Comment: Please provide a definition of "fractional knapsack"; if it is a problem formulation where items can be chosen partly, it is not necessary to use dynamic programming but can be solved in `O(n log n)` time by sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question is a bit broadly asked, different criteria for comparison might include:

- actual running time vs. instance quality, i.e. relative gap to an optimal solution
- implementation difficulty

As practical evaluation of algorithms is an involved subject, I suggest reading [A Theoretician's Guide to the Experimental Analysis of Algorithms](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/experguide.pdf) by Johnson to avoid some common pitfalls and misconceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution